# nao teleop and camera feed

Tags: nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I can't seem to get the Brown University Nao driver to work, nor the alufr (Freiburg) teleop package to work.  I'm using the new Nao h25 model, with NaoQi library included in the linux Choregraphe download (I believe it is version 1.10)

**[alufr]** What I am able to get is odometry and joint information, via running nao_ctrl/nao_sensors.py remotely.  When I run nao_ctrl/nao_walker.py, the robot will respond to "stand up" and "joystick control enabled" buttons, but won't actually walk.  I'm using a PS3 joystick, and I checked /joy topic and indeed the walk axes (specified in ps3joystick.yaml) are getting published.

**[brown]** When I run (locally on the robot) ./eyes, I am told "Could not get shared memory" (same issue as on [http://code.google.com/p/brown-ros-pkg/issues/detail?id=7]).  When I run control.py, I get SOAP errors of the form "setVolume not a member of tts" and "setStiffness not a member of motion" ...

Thanks for any assistance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10901/nao-teleop-and-camera-feed/) by [Nick Armstrong-Crews](https://answers.ros.org/users/885/nick-armstrong-crews/) on ROS Answers with karma: 481 on 2011-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK, got alufr joystick walking to work! I may not have been hitting the right button sequence; it seems the requirement is:

1. EnableControl button (robot speaks aloud "joystick control enabled")
2. InitPose button (robot stands up)
3. Walk around with joystick axes

I also may have been pointing to the wrong version of naoqi-sdk.

I am still having issues cross-compiling ROS for the nao... but I'll open a distinct ticket for that.

Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [Nick Armstrong-Crews](https://answers.ros.org/users/885/nick-armstrong-crews/) with karma: 481 on 2011-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe brown's camera driver comes precompiled for a specific disk image / NaoQI version. If it doesn't exactly match your version it won't work.

For walking, maybe the axis mapping is different on a ps3 joystick. I am usually using a Logitech Cordless Rumblepad. Are you starting the ps3controller.launch file from the nao_remote package? That's the one translating joystick axes into walking commands.

Can you try to `rostopic echo /cmd_vel` and hit a few axes on your gamepad? That is the topic which is sent to the Nao as walking velocity. Otherwise Daniel could maybe tell you more, as he's also using a ps3 gamepad with Nao.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2011-08-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

For alufr: did you try 'roslaunch nao_remote ps3controller.launch' prior to running teleop_nao_joy? This sets the mapping for the ps3 controller's buttons/axis used in teleop_nao_joy.

---

Originally posted by [daniel_maier](https://answers.ros.org/users/957/daniel_maier/) with karma: 290 on 2011-08-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1